# la instalación de java 8 se queda colgada

Tags: java, windows, windows7

Tengo problema al instalar java jdk (Windows 7 home premium)

1.-Lo descargo desde la pagina oficial

2.- Lo ejecuto y me sale la típica ventana de desea ejecutar este programa y le doy ejecutar.

3.- Una vez que le di ejecutar se queda cargando y no aparece la ventana de instalación, lo deje un rato y nada

Ya intenté todo, ejecutarlo como administrador y nada. También como super-administrador, tampoco funciona. ¿Qué hago?

Ya busque en foros, he hecho todo lo que dicen y nada que se puede instalar.

Mi equipo tiene una arquitectura de micro procesador de x64 bits. Hay veces que sale una ventana que dice "JAVA SE BINARY CMDSTAC". Esta es una imagen de la aplicación luego de esperar un momento a que procese:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu sistema operativo es para 32 o 64 bits?

Comment: Algún mensaje de error en los eventos de Windows?

Comment: @FredyDeLaCruz especificamente cual tratas de instalar : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: que versión te descargas te recomiendo el jdk 1.8? Prueba de desinstalar el java que tienes instalado

Comment: 8u101 y 8u102 Java SE Development Kit y ninguno de los dos funciona, lo desinstalaria si me dejara instalarlo, ya tambien limpie el registro y sigo con el mismo problema.   Si es el 1.8

Comment: ¿Has visto si tienes espacio en disco? ¿Has corroborado que durante la instalación tu equipo tiene memoria ram disponible y suficiente para instalar Java? También el mensaje de error te muestra un archivo log donde se ha registrado la excepción. Por favor accede a dicho archivo, revísalo y edita esta pregunta para que publiques el contenido relevante de dicho archivo (no necesitamos ver las miles de líneas en él, solo las líneas que nos permitan analizar el problema)

Comment: si tu disco duro es de motor físico (no ssd) intenta darle una defragmentación, en algunos casos los programas fallan por error de lectura del disco duro. Saludos

Answer (score 3):

Sigue los siguientes pasos:

1. Desinstala todas las versiones de Java que tengas instaladas en tu equipo. Sigue estos pasos de la pagina Oficial [¿Cómo puedo desinstalar Java de un equipo Windows?](https://www.java.com/es/download/help/uninstall_java.xml).
2. Limpia el Registro de Windows después de tu instalación. Sigue estos pasos de la pagina Oficial [¿Cómo puedo limpiar el registro después de una desinstalación incorrecta de Java?](https://www.java.com/es/download/help/manual_regedit.xml).
3. Reinicia tu computadora.
4. Verifica que cuentas con espacio en la unidad de disco donde intentas instalar el Java.
5. Descarga la versión de Java de acuerdo a tu arquitectura. En tu caso x64 para Windows. Esta es la liga oficial: [Java SE Development Kit 8u111](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u111-b14/jdk-8u111-windows-x64.exe).
6. Ejecuta el instalador como administrador.

Comment: [Java SE Development Kit 8u111] (http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u111-b14/jdk-8u111-windows-x64.exe)